# Regex for a malware scanner (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, malware

Good day all! Today's problem is simple.

We have many sites on shared servers and sometimes they get hacked by malware, they start to send email or they try to infect the rest of the neighborhood sites.

After a while spending time to clean up the files on many servers I started to think that maybe having a script that takes a look at the php files could be a really help for me.

Having a full antivirus for each website is a bit "too much" what I like to have is something I can manage remotely, and that will give me some clues on the scanned webserver.

So I thought about a simple PHP script, it simply scans every directory and every file in search of suspicious patterns. I actually use these two regex:

```
/eval\((base64|eval|\$_|\$\$|\$[A-Za-z_0-9\{]*(\(|\{|\[))/i

/mail\(/i
```

I know, the second one is very naive, but it makes the job, because I want to know if there is a mail call on some php file.

I have tried to use the `token_get_all` but the only useful token I found was the `T_EVAL` one, so I returned to the regex way.

My problem actually is that these two regex are:

1. un-optimized (I'm feeling regex is a bit to much cpu/time consuming)
2. far away to be precise

What I'm asking is:

1. got some better idea for achieving the same result?
2. I would like to match also these patterns:
   `ev​al(gzinflate(base​64_de​code('...');`
   `ev​al(gzuncompress(base​64_de​code('...');`
   `ev​al(gzinflate(str_rot13(base​64_de​code('...');`

I feel that `eval|base64|gzinflate|gzuncompress|gzinflate` should be the "initial" patterns to search for, but modifing the regexp into:

```
/eval\((base64|eval|gzinflate|gzuncompress|gzinflate\$_|\$\$|\$[A-Za-z_0-9\{]*(\(|\{|\[))/i
```

doesn't give me the results I espected.

Well, of course if you have better ideas, will be all more than welcome.

**NOTE**

I understand that the question is very broad, but I would like to have ideas on this topic since it is something very time consuming having to handle hundreds of websites without any kind of protection. 
If this isn't the right place to post this question, I'll delete it, I don't want to sully the board.

**ANOTHER NOTE**

This isn't "the solution" I only want a structured tool to start with in case of problems, something I can use easily from home (or with a CRON), that just warn me about something odd, there will be a tons of false positive indeed.

Comment: The time might be better spent auditing logs to see how the sites are hacked and fix/suspend sites that are vulnerable.

Comment: this can be the last option, websites owners want their site always up and runnig, don't want to pay any antivirus and I must find a way to be warned before them.
also, on shared servers, is not so easy to have php logs.

Comment: Such a tool might be a useful thing to have in your arsenal, but please, please, PLEASE don't think that this is an actual solution. The real solution should be tightening down whatever holes you have that allow such frequent infections!

Comment: of coruse, as you say, this is only one tool in the arsenal, is just something that can tell me that there is some problems (of course this will be not in any case the only one)

Comment: `on shared servers, is not so easy to have php logs` - What do you mean with this? With proper configuration every shared host should have own error log/ access log

Comment: Here (Italy) there are lot of hosting providers that gives the linux hosting, but only gives the ftp user that access the "public_html" directory, also, most of them simply don't give away any cpanel or anything. it is not so unusual.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is professional virus scan and malware removal software.  If you want to try to do this yourself, you might consider making a database of md5() digests of your PHP scripts.  Scan the directories, make the digests, store them in a database.  On a re-scan, compare the digests.  If there are any new digests (new PHP files appeared) or missing digests (PHP files went away) or changed digests (PHP files were modified) it would give you a quick heads-up that something was different, and you could investigate if the change was unexpected.

Comment: mmh, this is a nice idea, it isquite simple and gives an idea of what is going on on the server. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Once your server get hacked, there is no way to clean it**.

*The only safe way to proceed once an infection is detected is to build a new server and import the data into it (after a check of these data)*

If the server is infected you can't trust it anymore because he can lie to you about anything, like the content of files.

I know it sounds painful, but there is no hope to fully recover from an infection and be sure you have recover from it.

Comment: this is interesting, have you got some place where I can read something about this?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server is well documented. Most of the time you can clean the infection by just cleaning some php files, but the problem is you can't know **for sure** that it was the only problem. If the infection is deeper, your server can be fully compromised and lie to you about everything, if the attacker gained root access for example.